# css3pie select border-radius

Tags: select, css, css3pie

I am attempting to use CSS3PIE to round the edges of a select element. I am using the below code and running in IE7. The behaviour I get looks as though there are two rounded nodules in the bottom right of the select element. I would assume somehow the element is attempting to round the edges, but the proportions and/or position are not being passed for the created outer-element correctly. Anyone else have this issue or know how to fix it?

CSS

```
select
{
        behavior: url(http:\\pc-653336\APTEIT\HTC\PIE.htc);
}

select
{
    border:1px solid black;

    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="test.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="divy"><select></select></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you read this http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/ from start to end?

Comment: @biziclop Yes I have. Didn't see anything that seemed to help.

Comment: Behaviors need to be loaded from the same domain - try loading from a relative url.